# Display 'Choose an Option' in select as title only, not as option

Tags: magento2, select, option, title

I would like to keep the title 'Choose an Option' but when the user click on the dropdown, this label not appear in the proposition.
Did you know if it's possible ?

What I currently have and I don't want to change :
[image]

What I have when I click :
[image]

What I would like to have :
[image]

Someone know if it's possible ?

For information, I talk about the dropdown for size in the product page.

The phtml is here :

> src/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

And the Js here :

> src/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Magento is standard html select element behaviour.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Maybe you need to play around with CSS or the hidden attribute

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350843/how-can-i-hide-default-select-option-when-the-drop-down-is-clicked

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will take a look to your links